# Zip Archives get corrupted when uploading to Azure Blob Store using REST API

Tags: java, azure, rest, http, azure-blob-storage

I have been really banging my head against the wall with this one, uploading text files is fine, but when I upload a zip archive into my blob store -> it gets corrupted, and cannot be opened once downloaded.
Doing a hex compare (image below) of the original versus file that has been through Azure shows some subtle replacements have happened, but I cannot find the source of the change/corruption.
I have tried forcing UTF-8/Ascii/UTF-16, but found UTF-8 is probably correct, none have resolved the issue.
I have also tried different http libraries but got the same result.
Deployment environment is forcing unirest, and cannot use the Microsoft API (Which seems to work fine).

```
package blobQuickstart.blobAzureApp;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Base64;
import org.junit.Test;

import kong.unirest.HttpResponse;
import kong.unirest.Unirest;

public class StackOverflowExample {

    @Test
    public void uploadSmallZip() throws Exception {

        File testFile = new File("src/test/resources/zip/simple.zip");
        String blobStore = "secretstore";

        UploadedFile testUploadedFile = new UploadedFile();
        testUploadedFile.setName(testFile.getName());
        testUploadedFile.setFile(testFile);

        String contentType = "application/zip";

        String body = readFileContent(testFile);
        String url = "https://" + blobStore + ".blob.core.windows.net/naratest/" + testFile.getName() + "?sv=2020-02-10&ss=b&srt=o&sp=c&se=2021-09-07T20%3A10%3A50Z&st=2021-09-07T18%3A10%3A50Z&spr=https&sig=xvQTkCQcfMTwWSP5gXeTB5vHlCh2oZXvmvL3kaXRWQg%3D";

        HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.put(url)
                .header("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob").header("Content-Type", contentType)
                .body(body).asString();

        if (!response.isSuccess()) {
            System.out.println(response.getBody());
            throw new Exception("Failed to Upload File! Unexpected response code: " + response.getStatus());
        }
    }

    private static String readFileContent(File file) throws Exception {

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

        ByteArrayOutputStream answer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[8192];    
        int nbByteRead;    

        while ((nbByteRead = is.read(byteBuffer)) != -1) 
            {          
            answer.write(byteBuffer, 0, nbByteRead);        
            }    
        is.close();    

        byte[] fileContents = answer.toByteArray();
        String s = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileContents);
        byte[] resultBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(s);
        String encodedContents = new String(resultBytes);
        return encodedContents;
    }
}
```

[image: Hex Compare]

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    byte[] resultBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(s);
    String encodedContents = new String(resultBytes);
```

You are creating a String from a byte array containing binary data. String is only for printable characters. You do multiple pointless encoding/decoding just taking more memory.

If the content is in a ZIP format, it's binary, just return the byte array. Or you can encode the content, but then you should return the content encoded.  As a weakness, you're doing it all in memory, limiting potential size of the content.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if I had known that Unirest could handle a byte[] directly I would have tried this sooner, eventually I found the right syntax for this here: https://github.com/Kong/unirest-java/issues/248

Answer (score 0):

Unirest file handlers will by default force a multipart body - not supported by Azure.

A Byte Array can be provided directly as per this: https://github.com/Kong/unirest-java/issues/248

```
Unirest.put("http://somewhere")
                .body("abc".getBytes())
```